# Using a string resource to store a URL for a WebView.loadURL

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a string resource defined in strings.xml as follows:

```
<string name="web_app_url">http://BlueBadgeParking.com</string>
```

In one of my activities I attempt to get the string and assign it to a variable (I've tried this in the main activity class and in the onCreate class but the same thing happens):

```
String blueBadgeParkingURL = getResources().getString(R.string.web_app_url);
```

I then attempt to use this variable to load the URL in a WebView:

```
mWebView.loadUrl(blueBadgeParkingURL);
```

Manually entering the URL in the `loadUrl` call works fine, but when I try to use the variable set from the string resource the app crashes with "Unfortnately, {my_app_name} has stopped".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the error message in your log?

Comment: May you please post some more code and the exception? Is it possible, that you didn't initialize the webView and thus get a NullPointerException (just guessing...)?

Comment: Looks like this is the one: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.nooriginalthought.bluebadgeparking/com.nooriginalthought.bluebadgeparking.websiteViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference`, but as I say in the question, if I use `mWebView.loadUrl("http://BlueBadgeParking.com"); it works fine so it is  null pointer problem, but not on the WebView..

Comment: It sounds like you're calling `getResources()` outside of a method. Move the String initialization to inside `onCreate()`.

Comment: You're right Mike M,  I was declaring in the m!in activity class to make it available to all methods in that activity. I've used media's solution though as it seems a bit neater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
mWebView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.web_app_url));
```

Comment: See comment 3 to OP. I did try code similar to above as it is a cleaner way than creating a variable, but my code in the OP was an attempt to stop the crash by being more explict. It looks like the problem is accessing the resources.

Comment: @FatMonk hold control key and click on the resource to see if it takes you to `string.xml`

Comment: Oops, I'd left the `getResources` line in my code and it /was/ outside of any method (though it was within the class). It was that line that was causing the crash, but your code is far neater anyway and is what I was trying to achieve in the first place before expanding out to what I posted in the question..

Comment: Why has someone downvoted this? It has solved my problem and given me the functionality I wanted.

Comment: @FatMonk I know right... Good luck with your project ! ;)